# To invert a ttk.progressbar()

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple GUI based game with tkinter where I use `ttk.Progressbar` as a way to show the remaining health of my characters.

However, when I use `ttk.Progressbar.step(-x)`, it can only decrease the health of the character from the right to the left. Is there any way to 'invert' the progressbar so that the health decreases from left to right?

[image: Link to my image:]

Comment: The progressbar does not provide that option, but you could use a canvas and draw a couple of overlapping rectangles on it can to perform this task.